# Logout error Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

When I try to go `http://mysite/logout`, I get

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   No message

Routes:

```
Auth::routes();
```

part of `php artisan route:list`

```
+-----------+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Method    | URI                     | Name                | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+-----------+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| POST      | logout                  | logout              | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
```

When I use this default button

```
<a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
    onclick="event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
    Logout
</a>

<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

everything is ok.

---

Edit: my own answer added.

Comment: you need to make post request, here you are making get request

Comment: @Sohel0415 can I forbid GET for certain route?

Comment: yes, you are specifying this on route file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout', function () {
    return abort(404);
});
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

By default, the `Auth::routes()` uses the routes in `Illuminate\Routing\Router@auth` and the `/logout` is using the `POST` request. If you want to use the `GET` request, you may suffer some accidental log out. However, if you persist you may add like this on your routes:

```
<?php 
...
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
...
```

Comment: I need only `POST` for `logout`. I did `Auth::routes();
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');` but it didn't helped.

Comment: No need to write `Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');` as the `Auth::routes();` made that for you.

Comment: Then `Auth::routes()` is just fine. Just don't try to access the `/logout` via URL.

Comment: But if some user goes `/logout`, he might see 404, not current error, right? So maybe I need to redirect `logout` with `GET` to `404`?

Comment: Yes, you might want to check my created gist for you. https://gist.github.com/jayaregalinada/349b6088e46fc7ea08b0b5bf65ab5469

Answer (score 5):

In web.php, add route for logout,

```
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Solution, change "/logout" of href tag in form to "#".

The onClick event redirect to "/logout" and use POST METHOD in form.

Laravel 5.8.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">logout from account</button>
</form>
```

standard code , Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your route's method defined is different then the way you access it.

Change it as per the way you access it. Your route need to be defined as `POST` since you are submitting a form with `POST` method.

Comment: My route is `POST`. But if I try to access it as URL it's `GET`. I have to make a redirect?